# Error: cannot read properties of undefined (name): Firebase/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, vite

I am authenticating User from Firebase and following this [video](https://youtu.be/FOlFCLEyPAQ?list=PLW9nKlZ_Fyqj1e4Ltmbzsya0uH9mxTcW9&t=836).

With firebase v.9. changed syntax I get this error in my console:
[error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAB9Y.png)

**Here is my app.jsx**

```
export class App extends Component {
  

 state = {
    user: null,
}


componentDidMount() {

    // getting user info for navigation bar

    auth.onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
      console.log(user)
      if(user){
        const userid = user.uid;
    const userRef = await collection(db,'SignedUpUsersData')
    const docRef = doc(userRef, userid)
   await getDoc(docRef).then(snapshot => {
   
    console.log(snapshot.exists())   // -> false
    
    this.setState({
       user: snapshot.data().Name
      });
    })
    }
    
        else {
            this.setState({
                user: null
            })
        }
    })
    
  
}



render(){
    


  return (
    <>
     <ProductsContextProvider>
    <Router>
      
      <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element= {<Home user={this.state.user} />} />
```

**
Home.jsx**

```
export const Home = ({user}) => {
    return(
        <>
        <Navbar user={user} />
        <HeroSection />
        <Cards />
        
        </>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

Now, maybe it's worth to mention that snapshot.exists() is false ---> is that the issue?

Can someone help me out? really frustrates me....

thanks in advance,
carlos

PS:
I tried the following function from the doc, but didn'T work aswell

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("SignedInUsersData");
    docRef.once("value").then(function(snapshot){
      var key = snapshot.key;
      console.log(key)
```

EDIT:
I also do have a SignUp component, which saves my data to firestore. Apparently, it isn't uploading anything to firestore anymore, let alone with the right userCredentials (why?):
**My signUp() function:**

```
const signup = (e) => {
 let history = useNavigate();
 e.preventDefault();
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then(async (userCredential) => {
    const user = userCredential.user;
   const docRef=  await setDoc(doc(db, 'SignedUpUsersData', userCredential.user.uid),{
             Name: name,
             Email: email,
             Password: password
         }).then(() => {
             setName('');
             setEmail('');
             setPassword('');
             setError('');
             history.push({ pathname: '/login'});
             document.getElementById('file').value = '';
         }).catch(err => setError(err.message));
     }).catch(err => setError(err.message)); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`snapshot.exists() = false` is the reason for the error.

You are trying to read an empty `snapshot.data()`, which is null.
It is possible to protect from accessing a nullable/undefined property chain:

```
this.setState({ user: snapshot.data()?.Name ?? null });
```

The problem that value is null due the emptiness of a document from the next path:

```
const userRef = await collection(db,'SignedUpUsersData')
const docRef = doc(userRef, userid)
```

and that is equivalent to `'SignedUpUsersData/{userId}'`. Try to log `userId` and check you database records.

Comment: I did log in userid. I do get an id, but it is not equivalent to any document id (does it has to?)

Comment: Yes, you are trying to find a document that is not in your Firestore DB, so receiving `null`. Do you have a code place where the document data is saved to the database?

Comment: I edited the question, apparently my signup function doesn't work anymore... any ideas? got the setDoc function from the documentation..